# How to pass a testng.xml file in jenkins as parameter and run that particular testng.xml file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, testng

I want to pass a testing.xml file to jenkins as parameter and then run that particular testing.xml file.

Comment: Have you tried "File" parameter as part of "Parameterized Build" plugin?

Comment: So, what is your problem? What have you already tried?

Comment: Adding file parameter looks like a solution for me. I am able to add testng.xml file in my workspace and point my run to it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For handling properties files stored outside your repository, you have a plugin called "[Config File Provider Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/config-file-provider-plugin)".

It is capable of replacing tokens in json and xml or the whole file :

```
stage('Add Config files') {
        steps {
            configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'ID-of-file0in-jenkins', targetLocation: 'path/destinationfile')]) {
            // some block
            }
        }
}
```